CS0012 error when trying to do unit test on a method in a Form class in C# Win Forms?
I am working in Visual Studio 2022 Community, and in my project i came accross this error, which for the life of me can't figure out. Note i am not a developer, it's for a school project.
Windows Forms project target framework: .NET 4.7.2
Unit test project tartget framework: .NET 6.0
All base settings when creating the projects.

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public int Asdf() { return 1; }
        private int x = 1;
        public Form2()
        {
        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using WindowsFormsApp2;
using Xunit;

namespace TestProject1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Form2_Asdf_Returns1()
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            int actual = form2.Asdf();
            int expected = 1;
            Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
        }
    }
}


Above is a simplified version of what i am trying to test. Form2 is not the main form. in the test in line "int actual = form2.Asdf();" Asdf is red underlined and i am getting this error message:
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0012  The type 'Form' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'.
Anyone come accross this, if so what is the solution here?
Tried to test a method within a Form class, excpected to run just like a unit test would like with a basic class method. Resluted in CS0012 error.
Tried unit testing a method in a From class, expected to run smoothly as it would with a normal class, got cs0012 error.

In VS, open Solution Explorer. Right click on the project name, "Add Reference". Then "Assemblies > Framework" check the box for System.Windows.Form, and click OK.

Hi, thank you for the suggestion, i already tried that, but there is no Assemblies tab there for me, only Projects, Shared Projects, COM and Browse

You might be able to use browse, something like: C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NetFramework\v4.7.2\System.Windows.Forms.dll
